# What is up with this series/parallel calculation? Inverse Laplace looks strange

Tags: passive-networks, laplace-transform

I'm trying to find an analytic solution for this circuit. If the cap is inverted (series resistor to ground) the solution is straightforward. In this case I ended up with a strange cos term that makes no sense. Maybe there is an error or maybe there is a better way to express the solution? This isn't an academic exercise, but a real circuit I am working on.
[image]

Comment: your 1/s went missing half way down the page and reappeared in the next line, but only for the first term

Comment: Ya, I noticed. A C term disappeared and then reappeared as well. I will repost the whole thing once I finish the analytic solution. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You can double check your solution by noticing that the voltage across the capacitor starts at 0 and ends up at Vin R1/(R1+R2), charging with a time constant of (R1||R2)C.  You can see that the capacitor is charged by a simple thevinin source with impedance R1||R2.

Comment: Which is what I derived except I also ended up with the erroneous cos term. Ever had an interview at Apple? This (start and end point) is the kind of question I have been asked, haha.

Answer (score 0):

An RC circuit with one capacitor should be solved without such complexity, when the input is this simple. One should see immediately that the capacitor is  charged gradually. If C is empty at t=0 then Uo should be = Uin at t=0. That state evolves with time constant (R1*R2/(R1+R2))C towards

Uo=(R2/(R1+R2))*Uin. There's no cosine term.

U evolving from A to B with time constant T: U = A(exp(-t/T)) + B(1-exp(-t/T))

That's all this time.

Comment: "A mess" is how you can tell it is a real circuit and not an academic exercise. That's why you see the same worked out examples all the time: they are well behaved. I know what the behavior of the circuit is and have verified it via simulation. Obviously there is no cosine term which is what brings me here. I am just enough of a EE nerd to want to find the analytic solution. Thanks for your feedback though.

Comment: @duncan I removed the claim it looks messy. It looks messy only for practical electricians like me, who (due the lack of math skills) must avoid complex formulas to stay on the road. I have no idea how s/(s+A) becomes cosine . You should think it as an differentiated exponential.

Comment: No I get it. This is why academic (i.e. closed form solution) math often fails with real world problems and we resort to estimates or simulation. I've been an EE for 30+ years so I have a pretty good sense of what the quickest way to a practical solution is. I just think this is an interesting mathematical problem that is solvable.

Comment: I did not suggest any approximation. The state evolution with certain time constant is exact. And your cosine from s/(s+A) is something not true. As I said, you should think 1/(s+A) as an exponential and s/(s+A) should be thought as differentiated exponential. Initial value should be taken into the account! To keep the initial condition handling simple the equation should be formulated from the start for the capacitor voltage and Uo should be calculated after finding the analytical solution of the capacitor voltage. Uo=Uin-the capacitor voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "fast" resolution with a Maple sheet.
Your third line seems ok (my fcs), use this to apply \$Laplace^-1\$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is great! I totally forgot about Maple. It would be nice to see the steps, but the Maple solution looks correct (behaves how I know the circuit actually behaves). Using this result I can probably "reverse engineer" the steps to getting here. To bad I don't have enough points or whatever to upvote you.

Comment: If I remember well, Maple can show the steps used ... See the tutors" ...

Comment: you should perhaps see this https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inverse-laplace-calculator/inverse%20laplace%20%5Cfrac%7Bs%7D%7Bs%5E%7B2%7D%2B4s%2B5%7D?or=ex  NB: you can upvote ... later :-)

Comment: Nice. I tried another online laplace solver, but got an error; steps not supported, This linked one works as long as I only use two variables which is OK. I'll post the complete worked out solution in a bit. And I owe you an  upvote.